# Do all iPhones really delete themselves after 10 failed passcode attempts?

Tags: iphone

I don't actually own an Apple device, I'm just curious if what I just read is true:

Allegedly all iPhones have a function that locks them after 10 wrong passcodes were entered. There is a delay after each attempt, but over an hour or two anyone can enter 10 wrong passcodes. This function can not be turned off. After the phone is locked, the only course of action that remains is to connect the phone to a computer and erase all data that was stored on the phone.

Is this actually true?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question answered by me originally.  I can't find the original question.  But I'll give the answer anyway and let the moderator  make the call.

Comment: @jmh You can see all your answers on your [profile page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/235922/jmh?tab=answers)

Comment: Yea I know. I looked there but could'nt  find it.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't.  There is an option that has to be set on iPhones and if you set that option, it makes you wait longer times in between repeated attempts. If your phone gets stolen the thief can only  try 10 times and on 11th attempt the phone will erase. But again the owner has to set that option for it to take effect. Yes Apple allows the owner of the phone to set that up if they want to. And you can turn it off when you choose. The default setting is off.